# SQL and NOW() into bash script

Tags: sql, bash, datetime, insert

I have a file, "sharp.csv" in which data are like this :

```
<name>;<src_ip_address>;<mac_address>;<ip_address>;Vlan1;NOW()
```

Edit : These data are filled by a perl script
I want to insert these data into a SQL database with the help of a BASH script

```
+---------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field         | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+---------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| code_site     | varchar(64) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| ip_source     | varchar(64) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| mac_relevee   | varchar(64) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| ip_relevee    | varchar(64) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| vlan_concerne | varchar(64) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| date_polling  | datetime    | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+---------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

So my commands are just :

```
arp_router_file="$DIR/working-dir/sharp.csv"
db_arp_router_table="routeur_arp"
$mysql -h $db_address -u $db_user -p$db_passwd $db_name -e "load data local infile '$arp_router_file' REPLACE INTO TABLE $db_arp_router_table fields terminated by ';';"
```

But my *NOW()* command won't work.
Data are beeing inserted, but the "date_polling" row is filled with *"0000-00-00 00:00:00"*

Answer (score 1):

`NOW()` is a function but the `load data` command will treat all the fields in the input file as literal data, thus trying to insert `"NOW()"` in a `datetime` field. The string `"NOW()"` can't be converted to a valid datetime value, so you end up with the default "0000-00-00 00:00:00" value.

You will have to build actual SQL `INSERT` queries from your input file, you can do this using `awk`:

```
cat input_file.csv | awk -F';' '{print "INSERT INTO routeur_arp (code_site, ip_source, mac_relevee, ip_relevee, vlan_concerne, date_polling) VALUES (\"" $1 "\", \"" $2 "\", \"" $3 "\", \"" $4 "\", \"" $5 "\", " $6 ");"}' > sql_statements.sql
```

Comment: Well, i guess it'll be better to ask date to perl instead of SQL.
My data are coming from a perl Script. Instead of writing NOW() i should write something like "localtime()"

Comment: @GuiO If you've solved your problem, please `Answer your own Question` for future readers' references.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid sending NOW() instruction to MySQL, i'll send it a datetime with perl

```
use Time::Piece ;
my $t = localtime ;
my $date = $t->ymd;
my $time = $t->hms;
```

And instead of

```
<name>;<src_ip_address>;<mac_address>;<ip_address>;Vlan1;NOW()
```

It'll be

```
<name>;<src_ip_address>;<mac_address>;<ip_address>;Vlan1;$date $time\n
```

Perl send it as a String, MySQL understand is as a correct Datetime